# Copy multiple files from different folders to 1 folder

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy, copying, xcopy

i'm looking for a sollution to copy multiple files from different folders to 1 folder.

What I have is that I need to copy files from

c:\Customers\folderA\folderB\files

copy to e:\FolderB\files

The problem is that the "Customers" everytime is different. Also FolderA is different. Only FolderB is the same.

I've tried it with robocopy or with copy. But I always have to fill in the Customers name.

Can some one help me?

So I tried it into powershell

and i came to

Copy-Item -Path C:\customer -Recurse -filter *.xls -Destination e:\folderB -Force

only with this i filter to files and all the folders al copied. And i only want the files in it.

Comment: Here is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750311/get-childitem-and-copy-item-explanation

Comment: thats a powershell command. I don't know anything about powershell so i want do it with CMD

Comment: That's probably the worst attitude to have when trying to resolve IT problems.

Comment: Sorry , it was the worst attitude. My apollogies.... 

Thanks for the command Cyrill. Maybe its beter to try it on more way's the one wanted. I will see in to the powershell command to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FOR /D](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) command to loop through the **directories** in a path:

```
FOR /D %%I IN (C:\Customers\*) DO (
REM %%I is "C:\Customers\FolderA", etc.
    robocopy.exe /E "%%I\FolderB\files" "C:\FolderB\files"
)
```

Let's assume the directory **C:\Customers** contains:

- A. Datum Corporation
- AdventureWorks Cycles
- Alpine Ski House
- Awesome Computers
- Baldwin Museum of Science
- Blue Yonder Airlines

If we run this simple command script:

```
FOR /D %%I IN (C:\Customers\*) DO (
    ECHO %%I
)
```

We get this output:

```
C:\Customers\A. Datum Corporation
C:\Customers\AdventureWorks Cycles
C:\Customers\Alpine Ski House
C:\Customers\Awesome Computers
C:\Customers\Baldwin Museum of Science
C:\Customers\Blue Yonder Airlines
```

So taking that a step further, this command script:

```
FOR /D %%I IN (C:\Customers\*) DO (
    robocopy.exe /E "%%I\FolderB\files" "C:\FolderB\files"
)
```

Would run the following commands in sequence:

```
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\A. Datum Corporation" "C:\FolderB\files"
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\AdventureWorks Cycles" "C:\FolderB\files"
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\Alpine Ski House" "C:\FolderB\files"
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\Awesome Computers" "C:\FolderB\files"
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\Baldwin Museum of Science" "C:\FolderB\files"
robocopy.exe /E "C:\Customers\Blue Yonder Airlines" "C:\FolderB\files"
```

The output, of course, would be the result of each robocopy command.

Comment: thanks for the input, but the customer folder contains more than 100+ folders so to set them al its just almost like handwork.

or do I interpreteri  the format wrong?

Comment: The FOR loop should do what you're asking. I updated my answer with a couple examples to show how it works.

Comment: I don't understand why you are recommending dos command prompt if he talks about powershell

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can also use foreach

```
$SourceFolders = "C:\SourceFolder1\", "C:\SourceFolder2\", "C:\SourceFolder3\" # Add your source folders here
$DestinationFolder = "C:\DestinationFolder\" # Specify your destination folder

foreach ($SourceFolder in $SourceFolders) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $DestinationPath = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($SourceFolder.Length)
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 , this command worked for Me just now. It allowed Me to copy all My photos and videos from multiple sub folders, in to a completely different folder:

cd /d "E:__My Videos and Photography__My Videos and Photography"
for /r %%d in (*) do (copy "%%d" "E:\Temp_2\PhotosAndVIdeosFrom30years")

(Using the solution above, but simplified for any future readers)